# Invertendo a ordem de exibição com nodejs

Tags: node.js

Bom?
Gostaria de saber como que inverto a ordem de exibição dos itens do banco

```
async index(req, res){
    const docs = await Vag.find();
    return res.json(docs);
},

[
 {item1},
 {item2},
 {item3}
]
```

Se assim a ordem de exibição é crescente, como que faço para os dados serem exibidas de forma decrescente.

ps: estou usando o Mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por exemplo

```
db.orders.find().sort( { amount: -1 } )
```

usando o -1 a ordem fica decrescente "desc"

```
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : { "category" : "cookies", "type" : "chocolate chip" }, "amount" : 50 }
{ "_id" : 4, "item" : { "category" : "cake", "type" : "lemon" }, "amount" : 30 }
{ "_id" : 5, "item" : { "category" : "cake", "type" : "carrot" }, "amount" : 20 }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : { "category" : "cookies", "type" : "chocolate chip" }, "amount" : 15 }
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : { "category" : "cake", "type" : "chiffon" }, "amount" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 6, "item" : { "category" : "brownies", "type" : "blondie" }, "amount" : 10 }
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui, muito obrigado Mauro Rocha.

Comment: Legal! Boa sorte aí!